# Wordpress View profile page

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to create a public Profile page for wordpress. I have create a page named profile and created page file named profile.php in the current wp theme folder. Which is working correct for me.

The next I need to do is to rewrite the profile page as /profile/username, I have done server httaccess rewrites and add add_rewrite_rule function in it , But its not working properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

after extensive search, I have got answer to do that. The following page is describing about it.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/how-to-create-a-front-end-user-profile-with-a-friendly-permalink